# won't execute for loop in python selenium headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Without using selenium headless, the below code works fine. But with headless mode, why the for loop won't execute??

Here is my code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
url = "https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154-B8G6_BZDET"
driver.get(url)
try:
   pop_up = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="best_deal_detail_div"]/section/span')))
   pop_up.click()  # For disable pop-up
except TimeoutException:
   pass
while True:
   try:
      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load More Reviews..']")))
      element.click()

   except TimeoutException:
      break
   except:
      pass

 soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
 services = soup.find_all('span', {'class': "rName lng_commn"})
 for i in services:
      print(i.text)
```

I want to run this code with selenium headless. Please help.

Comment: What is the point of making all these actions in Selenium if you're trying to parse `driver.page_source`? Source code won't contain additional content. Also there is no need to use bs4 since you can do `[span.text for span in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.rName.lng_commn')]`

Answer (score 0):

Some websites behave different when they see your "headless" user-agent.

Try changing your user-agent to Chrome and see if it works.

```
options.add_argument("""user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)""")
```